# Create an outline based on density of raster

Tags: qgis, classification, circle, model

I have a classified aerial image of small vegetation that is separated enough by ground that it is not overlapping each other. After the classification process (dzetsaka), I removed all the other classes to only show the wanted vegetation. I am wondering if there is a way to draw a "circle" that best outlines the vegetation. This is currently a raster file, but I can convert it to a vector if need be. The random pieces around the main veg should be ground points, but were classified incorrectly. Likewise, the upper right additional piece should be shadow points.

I am unaware if there are any good models out there for this? I was thinking perhaps it could be done in excel? Or if there is a QGIS plugin? Unfortunately, I think I am going to have non-veg points classified as veg, so I am looking for something that will identify and draw the "circle" based on the dense part.

Any suggestions on where I might find some more information on something like this?

[image]

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------**
[image]

Comment: You could Sieve away the noise, convert to vector and then minimum bounding geometry

Comment: Would you suggest using Majority Filter to sieve noise?

Comment: I dont know. I have only used this Sieve (http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/6.2.0/grid_filter_15.html) which removes cluster less than a certain pixel count

Comment: Okay, I'll give both a try.

Comment: I'm still working on converting to vector, but due to the amount of pixels I have, it is taking a very, very long time. Is there a way to do it without converting to vector?

Comment: Why do you want a circle/elipse? Whats your next step?

Comment: I want to measure the area and also want each one to be separated to form a count.